# Tensorflow train.py cannot be found

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition)

I have Tensorflow installed (I've done it with Pip, Conda, and Docker, all saying it was successful). When I try to execute

python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py it always says that "python: can't open file 'tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". I searched my Mac for train.py and see one instance located at /Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python. I cd to that directory and try to do docker run -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow \python train.py but it still says the same thing ([Errno 2] No such file or directory".

I'm guessing it's some sort of installation issue, but I don't know how to fix it. I've literally tried every way I can find to install Tensorflow and none of them seem to work so I'm reaching out here for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you synced the TensorFlow repository? The tutorial starts with "To begin the training process, go to the TensorFlow source tree" so the implied assumption is that you have in fact got the source.

If you have synced the repo it is in fact in there if you have not you will need to do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py
```

Choose a suitable place for it (I put git repositories in ~/git).

Comment: That's all there was to it. I was thinking that it was part of the install done but obviously not. Thanks!